# In OpenGrok how to search a substring?

Tags: opengrok

I have a source file that contains statement like:

```
    CRITICAL_MSG("\tprobe and attach devices\n");
```

but I cannot find the string in the "full" field by typing "probe and attach devices".  I cannot use wildcard "*probe and attach devices*" either.  I have to input the exact string and the backslash: "\\tprobe and attach devices\\n".

So how to find this string?

Comment: I found I could search "and attach devices" as a workaround.